# axios POST request throwing 500 error after saving data properly in database

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

I am developing an online shop, I am using axios to save some products into my database. Everything seems to work fine, the viewmodel passed to the controller is populated with the right data, and after that the program flow heads to the CreateProduct method where the product is perfectly saved into my DB, yet, after the request is completed, I check the console and I see a 500 POST error. I literally have not a clue what I am doing wrong, I'm attaching the code below:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    loading: false,
    productModel: {
        CategoryId: 1,
        BrandId: 5,
        ImageId: 7,
        Name: "Product Name",
        Description: "Product Description",
        Price: 1.99
    },
    products: []
},
methods: {
    getProducts() {
        this.loading = true;
        axios.get('Admin/products').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.products = res.data;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        }).then(this.loading = false);
    },
    createProduct() {
        this.loading = true;
        axios.post('Admin/products', this.productModel).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        }).then(this.loading = false);
    }
}
```

});

And the controller action is the following:

```
    [HttpPost("products")]
    public IActionResult CreateProduct([FromBody] ProductViewModel productViewModel) => Ok(new CreateProduct(_context).Create(productViewModel));
```

And this is my ProductViewModelClass

```
    public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 500 error means internal server error, you should debug the CreateProduct action and see whats throwing an exception in there

Comment: I did, nothing errors in my backend code, it's so weird. This is the last line of code executed: await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); and it doesn't throw any error, only in the chrome console, but after the product is saved.

Comment: Can you add the ProductViewModel class to your question

Comment: @AliKleit just did, see update please, I'm using .NET Core 3 if that helps

Comment: ok now try chaning `int` to `int?`  for the `Id` and all nullable props

Comment: I just tried, same error, and the product still saving to the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214608/discussion-between-ali-kleit-and-tofetopo).